# Code is right but still facing some problem with output

Tags: java

I'm getting an error in my Rock, Paper, Scissors game:

```
ERROR: The value of local variable ROCK SCISSOR PAPER types is not used
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RockPaperScissor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println("Player: Type '1' For ROCK \n Type '2' For Scissors \n Type '3' for Paper");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice");
        Integer a = scan.nextInt();
        Integer ROCK = 1;
        Integer SCISSOR = 2;
        Integer PAPER = 3;
        char[] types = {'r','p','s'};
        Integer rand = random.nextInt(3);
        while (rand==1) {
            System.out.println(rand);
            if (a==3) {
                System.out.println("You Win!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry! Better luck next time.");
        }
        break;
    }
        while (rand==2) {
            System.out.println(rand);
            if (a==1) {
                System.out.println("You Win!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry! Better luck next time.");
            }
            break;
        }
        while (rand==3) {
            System.out.println(rand);
            if (a==2) {
                System.out.println("You Win!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry! Better luck next time.");
            }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are getting is not an error but a warning since you are not using the constants ROCK, SCISSOR, PAPER. I was able to run the code without issue https://onecompiler.com/java/3ycyzb3z7 (put in stdin 1 or something).

To solve it, I think you should replace a==3 to a == PAPER when doing your checks to improve readability.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

You declare variables

```
Integer ROCK = 1;
Integer SCISSOR = 2;
Integer PAPER = 3;
```

but then never make use of them. This is absolutely legal but not a good practice. So I'm wondering why the compiler should error out. But maybe you have more checks than just the compiler.

Either turn off the checks, remove the variables or simply make use of them.

BTW, your code has more issues but you need to learn fixing them one by one.

Comment: Where should I use these variables... Code is right and running

Comment: If using them is nothing you can think of, turn off the checks or remove them.